# PHP 5 Hashalgorythm for PHPSESSID

Tags: php

i just search on google a lot about PHPSESSID and i coudn't figure out which Hashalgorythm they are using currently.
I installed PHP 5.5 on my Rootserver and check my session ID, i realiced that the current ID looks like this **3teao7a72gcg98pgelupl1p9l3**.
If you look on older Version of php they used the MD5 Algorythm to Hash the Data that is used for Sessions, if i am right it was something like ***IP:TIMESTAMP:PHPRAND:SYSTEMRAND*** hashed to MD5 building your sessionid.
I checked my **php.ini** and looked at the property at for the Hashfunction for Session

```
; Select a hash function for use in generating session ids.
; Possible Values
;   0  (MD5 128 bits)
;   1  (SHA-1 160 bits)
; This option may also be set to the name of any hash function supported by
; the hash extension. A list of available hashes is returned by the hash_algos()
; function.
; http://php.net/session.hash-function
session.hash_function = 0
```

Now i wounder wich Algorythm realy represent the PHPSESSID, i check it with some Hash Identiefier but coudn't get a result, do you know some Sites were i can have a look at the function that generates the PHPSESSID?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c

Comment: @MarkBaker are you pointing to the `bin_to_readable()` function? Btw. I like the rainbow elephpant :-)

Comment: I was pointing more specifically to `php_session_create_id()` though that does call `bin_to_readable()`... and glad that you like Enfys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `session.hash_function` is 0, then it is MD5.

You're just used to seeing it hex-encoded, while PHP's session extension may encode it differently based on the `session.hash_bits_per_character` setting.

There's a lot of hard to follow logic behind it, but basically this is the end result:

```
$hash_bits_per_character = ini_get('session.hash_bits_per_character');
$hash_function           = ini_get('session.hash_function');
switch ($hash_function) {
    case 0:
         $hash_function = 'md5';
         break;
    case 1:
         $hash_function = 'sha1';
         break;
    default:
         break;
}

$digest_size = mb_strlen(hash($hash_function, 'dummy', true), '8bit') * 4; // 128; 
$sid_length  = (int) ceil($digest_size / $hash_bits_per_character);
```

When you have `session.hash_bits_per_character = 4` (the default value), that's the same as hex encoding, so only `0-9a-f` characters will be used. But when the value is higher, more characters are necessary in order to be able to pack more data in a single character.

These are the possibilities:

- `4`: `0-9a-f` characters (hex-encoding)
- `5`: `0-9a-v` characters
- `6`: `0-9a-zA-Z,-` characters

Judging by the length of the example ID you've shown, I'd say you have `session.hash_bits_per_character = 5`.

---

All of this doesn't apply to PHP 7.1+, where:

- `session.hash_bits_per_character` was replaced with `session.sid_bits_per_character`
- `session.hash_function` was removed and you directly supply `session.sid_length`

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. Default MD5 cut some of the bits that are the result of the messagediggest, if you use more chars that means that there are less bits thrown away and user for the resulting hash string?

Comment: Well, I have to correct you: MD5 is still MD5 ... it won't cut anything. Higher bits_per_character will effectively "compress" the data, resulting in a shorter string, but none of it is actually lost.